# Compiler crashing due to linked list error (?)

Tags: c, list, crash, linked-list

```
Sim simulacao(Sim lista, int lin, int col, int dim)
{

    int conta;
    int contador_conta;
    int x, y; //x=linha, y=col
    char tipo;
    int pop1;

    conta = ((lin * col) * dim) / 100; //nr de células a serem preenchidas
    contador_conta = conta;
    pop1 = conta / 2;
    while (contador_conta != 0)
    {
        contador_conta--;
        x = numero_random(1, lin);
        y = numero_random(1, col);
        if (pop1 != 0)
        {
            tipo = 'O';
            printf("%d\n", x);
            lista = adiciona(lista, x, y, tipo);
            printf("%d\n", x);
            pop1--;
        }
        else
        {
            tipo = 'X';
            lista = adiciona(lista, x, y, tipo);
        }

    }

    return lista;
}

Sim adiciona(Sim lista, int x, int y, char tipo)
{

    Sim novo, aux;

    novo = (Sim)malloc(sizeof(lista));
    if (novo == NULL) //verifica se alocou o espaço com sucesso
    {
        printf("Erro na alocacao de memoria!\n");
        return lista;
    }
    printf("%d\n", x);
    novo->linha = x;
    novo->coluna = y;
    printf("%d\n", x);
    novo->tipo = tipo;
    novo->prox = NULL;
    if (lista == NULL)
    {
        lista = novo; //se a lista estiver vazia, insere no topo da lista
    }
    else
    {
        aux = lista; //insere no fim da lista
        while (aux->prox != NULL)
            aux = aux->prox;
        aux->prox = novo;
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return lista;
}
```

I'm having a problem when compiling my code, it crashes after running the adiciona function 2 times. I've placed some printf's in order to check when it crashes, however i've been looking for the errors and i can't find it :/
Any thoughts on what's the problem?

[picture of the crash/error](http://imageshack.com/a/img844/4017/a4db.jpg)

Comment: So you really mean it crashes when you *run* your code. I assume the compile completed without errors or warnings?

Comment: If your code is running, then the compiler is not crashing.

Comment: it looks like the problem was the allocating memory phase, anyway, it is solved now, ty guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
novo=(Sim)malloc(sizeof(lista));
```

You are allocating for the pointer size not for the pointee. Change this to:

```
novo = malloc(sizeof *lista);
```

Comment: god, i'm feeling stupid xD
thank you mate, it works now!